# MVVM in WPF with Entity Framework unhandled exception

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, mvvm

This is driving me mad. I'm fairly new to WPF/EF.

I have a simple MVVM app which reads an Entity Table into a DataGrid via binding in the XAML. The app compiles fine.

I am getting this unhandled exception however which locks the designer:

```
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString)
```

The XAML cannot create an instance of my View Model...

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Entity_MVVM"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800"
    DataContext="{DynamicResource MyViewModel}">
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:CountrysViewModel x:Key="MyViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Here is my View Model 'Load Grid' method:

```
 public void LoadGrid()

    {
        var db = new LDBEntities();
        using (var conn = new EntityConnection("name=LDBEntities"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            EntityCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT VALUE c FROM LDBEntities.tbCountrys as c";

            try
            {
                EntityDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess | CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                _CountrysModelObservableList.Clear();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    var cCountryId = rdr["CountryId"].ToString();
                    var cShortName = rdr["shortName"].ToString();
                    var cLongName = rdr["longName"].ToString();

                    _CountrysModelView = new CountrysModel()
                    {
                        CountryId = cCountryId,
                        ShortName = cShortName,
                        LongName = cLongName
                    };

                    _CountrysModelObservableList.Add(_CountrysModelView);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Can't read in data!"));
            }
        }
```

The connection string in my App.config was created on creation of my EF model and populates the DataGrid as intended.

Any ideas what is causing this?

Friday afternoon frustration! Thanks

Edit: App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="LDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=DMEA-T1000\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=PasswordHidden;MultipleActiveResultSets=True' " providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What version of EF? 4?

Comment: IMO, using Entity Framework like that (as if it were plain old ADO.Net with all those magic strings stuff and manual mapping) completely defeats the purpose of an ORM.

Comment: Post your App.config. One way this occurs is if your data model can't connect to the source. This obviously occurs at runtime, which is why it compiles fine.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to understand an existing app written by a departed dev. I agree, I would have used LINQ and not EntityDataReader etc.

Comment: @hardgraf that code is all wrong. Delete it and redo it properly and it will save you time and suffering.

Comment: Ok added the app.config code. I cannot re-write it, I just need to understand the logic as I will be responsible for debugging/adding functionality.

Comment: Your connection string isn't valid.  Not sure what this has to do with WPF or MVVM.  Fix your connection string.  Also, second the dismay at using EF to do ADO.  Its bizarre.

Comment: Yes, as I said, not my doing. Just trying to understand the code of another. Surely if the connection string was not valid, I could not query the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your ERM to the project it will create models for you.

If you have a table in your db called tblYears for example you should be able to declare:

```
tblYear y = new tblYear();
```

I personally create a local model and populate it to use in the view i.e. viewmodel.

```
class YearModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

#region Members

    MyERM.tblYear _year;

#endregion

#region Properties

    public MyERM.tblYear Year
    {
        get { return _year; }
    }

    public Int32 id
    {
        get { return Year.id; }
        set
        {
            Year.id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("id");
        }
    }

    public String Description
    {
        get { return Year.Description; }
        set
        {
            Year.Description = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }

#endregion

#region Construction

    public YearModel()
    {
        this._year = new MyERM.Year
        {
            id = 0,
            Description = ""
        };
    }

#endregion
}
```

You can then use this view model to either populate a List<> or as an individual record - list example:

```
class YearListModel
{
    myERM db = new myERM();

    #region Members

    private ObservableCollection<YearModel> _years;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<YearModel> Years
    {
        get { return _years; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Construction

    public YearListModel()
    {
        _years = new ObservableCollection<YearModel>();

        foreach (MyERM.tblYear y in db.tblYears())
        {
            _years.Add(new YearModel
            {
                id = y.id,
                Description = y.Description
            }
          );
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then for example you can send it to a page like so:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"

<Page.Resources>
    <local:YearListModel x:Key="YearList" />
</Page.Resources>
```

And bind it to a control:

```
<ListView x:Name="listviewname"
          DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=YearList}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Years}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="columnname" Header="Code" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Code}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Hope this helps GL

Comment: Great, thankyou so much for your help! With only 1 year's programming/c# experience this simplifies things greatly.

Comment: I can't seem to create an object for MyERM.TableName (in my case LDBEntities.tbCountrys)

Comment: If you have added it to the database since adding the instance of the erm you need to refresh the erm. If the refresh does not work (buggy), copy the name, delete it and re add it using same name. Then any update in the database will be reflected in the erm. I have to do this many times so it is a practice to get used to. Change database - re attach edm (if refresh does not work).